# Why can't I connect to my Solr server?

Tags: search

I am attempting to configure Solr search with a drupal web page on a dev server.
I have installed the server and the Search_API_Solr modules along with it's dependencies.  When I try to connect the Search_API_Solr module to my server, I get the error:

> The Solr server could not be reached.  Further data is therefore unavailable.
>
> **SOLR SERVER URI**: http:// host_machine:8983/solr/#
>
> **CONNECTION**: The Solr server could not be reached.  Further data is therefore unavailable.
>
> [image]

To attempt to remedy this, I've tried linking directly to the core that I have setup (e.g. http://host_machine:8983/solr/mycorename) to no success.

Does anyone have any experience fixing this?  I've searched through every bug/support post I came across and attempted all of the solutions with no fix.

P.S. I've read somewhere that you can't access a Solr server if the Drupal site is running on the same host. I don't know the validity of that.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that if you use the IP of your host machine, if you're hosting Solr and the Site on the same box, you can't use the IP of the box to connect.  In my case, I was trying xx.xx.xx.xx:8983/solr/my_core which was failing.

After changing the address to http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/my_core I am finally connected.